# How to sum matrix (vector) elements in a structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, sum

I have a `M x N` sized structure array with fields `var` and `val` which are vectors.

What I would like to do is to get an `M x N` sized matrix `A` where each element `A(i, j)` contains the sum value of vector `var` (or `val`) from structure array

For example:

```
myStructure(1,5)

ans = 

    var: 1
    val: [0.0100 0.1800 0.8100]

sum(myStructure(1,5).val)

ans = 

    1

myStructure(7,8)

ans = 

     var: [1 3]
     val: [1x9 double]

myStructure(7,8).val

ans =

  Columns 1 through 6

    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111

  Columns 7 through 9

    0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
```

**Therefore `A(1,5)` should be 1 and the same way all elements `A(i,j)` should be equal to `sum(myStructure(i,j).val)`.**

Does anyone know how this could be done in Matlab without using for loops?

I've tried to use sum function in a number of ways (`sum(messages.val)` and `sum(messages(:,:).val)` ...) but couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: Is the `val` vector field allways the same length? eg 3 in your example? or can it vary?

Comment: the val length can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field elements into one matrix using:

```
svals = [myStructure.val];
```

If `val` is always the same length (let's name it `P`), this'll be a `numel(myStructure)*P  x 1` vector containing all values of all fields in sequence. You can [reshape](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) it of course back:

```
[N,M]=size(myStructure);
P = numel(myStructure(1,1).val);
svals = reshape(svals,[P M N]);
```

and now just sum the first dimension, which leaves you the `MxN` sized `A` matrix:

```
A = squeeze(sum(svals,1));
```

[squeeze](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) is applied in this last step to remove the resulting singleton dimension (otherwise `A` would be of size `1xMxN`).

If the `val`length can vary, I see no other way than looping it, or using [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html), which is essentially the same as looping:

```
A = arrayfun(@(x) sum(x.val),myStructure);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different solution. First lets create an array structure for testing:

```
s = struct();
for i=1:5
    for j=1:3
        s(i,j).var = i+j;
        s(i,j).val = rand(1,randi(10));  %# different lengths vectors
    end
end
```

Now we do the sum:

```
A = cellfun(@sum, reshape({s.val}, size(s)))

A =
       1.9278       3.0719       5.8731
       3.2377      0.43874       2.2374
       3.0661       2.8892       4.1455
       1.9093       1.4758        1.441
       4.8731       0.5308       3.4076
```